# Laravel inner join with cast

Tags: php, database, laravel, inner-join, laravel-8

In db one filed is varbit the other field int4. So I am trying to do cast with inner join in Laravel.

But it isnt work

```
 ->join('be_product','be_product.id','=',
  'DB::raw('CAST('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.product_id' AS INT'))')
        ->where('id','=',$id)
```

How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Your code has syntax error because of single quotes usage. Also mysql `Cast` function does not have `INT` type casting. You can use `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` for integer type casting. Can you try this:

`->join('be_product','be_product.id','=',DB::raw('CAST("be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.product_id" AS UNSIGNED)'))->where('id','=',$id)`

Answer (score 0):

Please remove single quote from `DB::raw`. See blow

```
->join('be_product','be_product.id','=',
  DB::raw("CAST('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.product_id' AS UNSIGNED)"))
        ->where('id','=',$id)
```